# How to rebuild the iOS Picker animation in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, scrollview, picker

Is there a way in React Native to rebuild the iOS picker component completely in Java Script? I don't need the common picker, but a normal scroll view with a similar fade-out effect like the iOS picker.

[image]

EDIT – I think I have not explained my initial answer exactly enough. This is why I complete it here:

I want to build a scroll view that takes over the whole screen. It's not supposed to give the user the possibility to elect some item, like the the iOS Picker does. Nevertheless, it's supposed to be a 'normal' scroll view, that shows the user some information, e.g. different chats, tasks, news and so on.

The only difference to React Native's common scroll view should be the fade-out effect at the top: When the user scrolls the content up, it should not just leave the screen at its top edge, but it should use the iOS Picker's fade-out effect (see picture).

This fade-out effect is made up of two parts: First of all, it raises the content's transparency with a decreasing y-coordinate. Furthermore, this content seems to escape into the third dimension.

My problem is, that I don't see a way to achieve this three-dimensionality of the content in React Native. I've to add, that the content in my scroll view does not consist of small, equally sized items (like e.g. the texts 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3',...), but of bigger items with different sizes like images or whole textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [NPM module](https://github.com/puredazzle/react-native-simple-picker) to get what you want. That module works the same in Android and iOS. Do not reinvent the wheel :)

EDIT: Now I've understood what you want. You can try this snack that I've made for you:

https://snack.expo.io/r1qnxSt9m

Of course you need to improve it, but it's a beginning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think, you‘ve misunderstood my question. I don’t want to rebuild the whole Picker, but only its fade-out effect. I want to apply this effect to a common scroll view, that I use in my app to have a nice fade-out at its top...

Comment: @Paul you can download the source code of the NPM module that I've mentioned before. Take a look on how it does that effect. I think it uses react-native-animatable (https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable)

Comment: @shimatai Thank you for this idea! Unfortunately, react-native-simple-picker uses React Natives' Picker component, which then again uses iOS' native picker component. That means, that the desired fade-out effect is not directly included in react-native-simple-picker. Do you have any other idea to achieve the desired effect in React Native? I will have a look on react-native-animatable...

Comment: @Paul if you're using `ListView` component, on `renderRow` method you can apply a custom style to the current item. If the current item isn't the selected one, than you can apply that fade style. The `renderRow` method has the rowID that lets you know on which position of the array you are.

Comment: @shimatai Thank you very much for your help. I think, I have not explained my request exactly enough. That is why I have updated my initial question.

Comment: Thanks for this Snack. Unfortunately I am searching for a fade-out effect for content, that "does not consist of small, equally sized items (like e.g. the texts 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3',...), but of bigger items with different sizes like images or whole textboxes" (see edit in the question). For such content your method does not work. But I will use your Snack as an inspiration for an own solution.

Comment: @Paul you can set some style to each item, that's the easy part. The hard part is to detect which items you want to apply a different style.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect with the Animated api. The idea is to set different input ranges to the items in your list. You then hook the opacity to the scroll value of your ScrollView (or any list component). I have simplified the code, but it should be enough to demonstrate the idea.

The example below only demonstrates an opacity effect, but you could easily add a translate effect to get the exact animation that you are looking for.

```
const data = []; // array that contains the text
const items = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  const distanceFromViewCenter = Math.abs(i * ITEM_HEIGHT);
  const inputRange = [
    -distanceFromViewCenter - 2 * ITEM_HEIGHT,
    -distanceFromViewCenter - ITEM_HEIGHT,
    -distanceFromViewCenter, // Middle of picker            
    -distanceFromViewCenter + ITEM_HEIGHT,
    -distanceFromViewCenter + 2 * ITEM_HEIGHT,
  ];
  items.push(
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        opacity: this._scrollValue.interpolate({
          inputRange,
          outputRange: [0.0, 0.3, 1.0, 0.3, 0.0],
        }),
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ height: ITEM_HEIGHT }}>{data[i]}</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  )
}

<ScrollView
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this._scrollValue } } }],
    { useNativeDriver: true }
  )}
>
  {items}
</ScrollView>
```